# conan versioning - get the highest patch of a version on conan install

Tags: versioning, patch, conan

The conan packge uses git version Major.Minor.Patch
I would like to get always the highest patch of a package.
If I have versions 6.5.1 , 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.6.1, ....
When asking for 6.5 I would like to get 6.5.3 (but no latest e.g. 6.6.2).

something like
pack/[6.5.x]@mysite.stable -> should give me 6.5.3

Pls. knows someone the solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are currently supported [Version Ranges](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/versioning/version_ranges.html) in Conan which could possibly be used as solution for your problem. To my knowledge there is no other way of forcing Conan to get latest patch version when it's not provided. Be careful as version ranges might not work with all packages, i.e OpenSSL uses versions with letter at the end (OpenSSL1.1.1l). You can find more information in the link I have provided. There was also [Github issue](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/15) created before Version Ranges where introduced which you might find out interesting.

Edit: to my knowledge there is no other way of forcing Conan to get latest (minor -> patch) version

Comment: Major and Minor are known and fix.
Only for the patch I would like to get the higest one.
I know about special version but there I won't use it.

The range isn't clear to me, because I'm afraid that it will take the first it finds (e.g. in local cache). So I might not get the highest patch.

Comment: Version ranges that match against multiple versions, will select the latest version. You could write ``[>=6.5.0 <6.6]`` or you can also try ``[~6.5]``

Comment: `[~6.5]` would work fine (downloading 6.5.3) if there is not yet e.g. 6.5.1 in the local cache. 
If there was one already downloaded it doesn't look for a newer.
As I use "conanfile.txt" to define the packages I would need an additional parameter at such package to tell conan  to look for a newer.

Comment: Param '-u' at conan install helps to get a newer from remote.
But unfortunately it also checks the other 20 packages with fixed version already in local cache too. I would need it only 2 the to set with `[~6.5]`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this reference format when I need to install the *latest* version of `conan_test` package:

```
$ conan install "conan_test/[>=0.0.1]@" --update
```

Installs the latest version that follows `semver`.

N.B. [version range > 0.0.1](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/versioning/version_ranges.html) and `--update` are used.

For `6.5`, you can use:

```
$ conan install "conan_test/[~6.5]@" --update
```

or

```
$ conan install "conan_test/[>=6.5]@" --update
```

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading because `[>=6.5]` will select a `6.6.x` version or higher if available, which is not what the OP wants and is *not* equivalent to `[~6.5]`.